# How to add css to a child component from parent component if i'm using modular CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-selectors, styles

In my project i have 3 simple components: List , Table and Item. The item component is the children of both the List and Table component, and both List and Table components are rendered on different routes say ("/list" and "/table"). Each component my react app has modular CSS, so my problem is that, when i go the  component, i want to make CSS styling changes to the
Item component, and when i go the  component i want to some different CSS styling changes to the  component. Is there any way i can achieve this without added multiple classes and using a normal CSS files, or CSS child selectors.

Comment: I would set up basic styling for '.item' that is generic, then use the parent component class names '.list.item' and '.table.item' to setup specific styling? This assumes you are not using css in js however.

Comment: That is a wonderful idea ,but then i would have to conditionally render the item component with a different class name depending upon the parent component i'm in? or maybe there is some other way of doing that?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code I'm not sure exactly what you mean or how your app is structured, but like I say my solution is more about traditional css rather than css in js. For example I would have a css file for List which is imported inside that component that also includes styles for `.list.item` for example.